# How to show JavaScript variable in colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I use `colorbox` jquery and have problem to show variable in colorbox.

I have variable called `wp_store_caption` that get value from input type :-

```
<input type="text" id="title" class="ab_form_text wp_store_caption require" name="wp_store_caption" value="">
```

Now i use colorbox like :-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var wp_store_caption = jQuery('#title').val();
    jQuery(".open-popup-link").colorbox({html:"<h1>"+wp_store_caption+"</h1>"});

});
```

But canot show value of `wp_store_caption`, But when use `alert()` without colorbox, I can see the value.

Where is problem ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not happening because when you write

```
jQuery(".open-popup-link").colorbox({html:"<h1>"+wp_store_caption+"</h1>"})
```

you bind the value of `wp_store_caption`, which is initially not defined.

You need to bind click event and assign value to `wp_store_caption`, and then call colorbox function.

You should write this:

```
$(".open-popup-link").click(function () {
    $.colorbox({
        html: "<h1>" + $('#title').val() + "</h1>"
    });
});
```

[**See DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsrrkgss/)

[**In this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsrrkgss/1/), I have predefined value of title. Please note this value will not update the heading in colorbox because the value of -`wp_store_caption` is not being updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to .blur() to get it work as [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EJ2015/r63vanb2/).

```
$(function() {
  $('#title').blur(function(){
  var wp_store_caption = $('#title').val();
    if (wp_store_caption.length > 0)
      $.colorbox({html:"<p>" + wp_store_caption + "</p>"})
 });
});
```